# Webpack built package runs fine on localhost, broken on server

Tags: reactjs, webpack, server, ftp, http-status-code-404

So I have a react app that I am bundling using webpack, which is complete black magic for me. However, I can get it to build the site and if I use simple http server through python I can see the website and everything runs fine. So the build works! However, when I transfer all the contents of the dist folder over to my FTP server by putting it in the public_html folder on my server side there's something broken. When I navigate to my website I get this:

```
vendor.1ef2345b1b27ea00e944.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
app.00a6dbb5503f500f33b7.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Well....neither of those two files are anywhere in my dist folder. My only guess is that webpack is referencing those files somehow and I don't have any idea how to debug this. I've used this process to get my site up (once) before, so I thought it should work fine, but evidently not. Completely flumoxed, any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT: Ok, so now only the app file is missing, but I don't know what changed. So good, I guess?

Comment: pretty hard to tell what's going wrong when you don't give us any code! is your python server supposed to serve the react app?

Comment: I dont know what to tell you. Webpack is this massive module with a crap ton of moving parts. What part of the code do you want me to show, because I have no idea what any of this does. I could just link to my repo if you want.

Comment: Share your python code. Also, are you sure those files are named the same on your server?

Comment: Please share some code for elaborate more..

Comment: @PeterWeyand could you please share config file ?

Answer (score -1):

So, apparently sometimes webpack will include the wrong path to the minimized js file. I had no idea that it would do this. Dang it webpack.